# Can there be permissions/limitations with browsers over a network?

Tags: windows, networking, permissions, internet-explorer, database

I'm part of a network at my job and the only thing that can be accessed from my/my co-workers computers is the company database and sharepoint. These are accessed through IE. Everything else is denied through permissions. I know this is done to disallow non-work oriented internet browsing. Is there any way to implement permissions over a network on a browser to only allow work-oriented browsing?

Comment: what is the question, you just have answered it yourself?

Comment: I agree with @g24l, this sounds like Christopher said, "My company network does X. Is it possible to do X?" Well, obviously it's possible to do X, because you just told us your company network already does it. Perhaps the question he meant to ask was, "HOW is this possible?" or "How did they accomplish this?"

Comment: @g24l and Spiff: Just realized after posting that the question sounds redundant. I guess what I was meaning to say is, is it possible to implement permissions on a specific browser? I work in medical market research. So work-oriented browsing would be only allow websites like WebMd, Vitals, hospital websites, etc to be accessed and deny sites like social network sites and the such.

Comment: you usually do it on the company proxy/network level . Usually, maintaining policies all over the company site it is difficult and has many holes. Also you can do it only for IE, chrome and firefox will pretty much ignore WINDOWS AD policies. That is why sane administrators work on the proxy level for such matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches, and based on the concrete requirements, there are good ones and bad ones.

A very simple, but effective possibility would be to limit the browsing experience by enforcing the use of a company proxy server and/or by allowing provided URLs by a firewall (and block every other content). The downside of this approach is that such a solution is often "crafted" for specific situations and therefore not maintainable without larger efforts.

A more professional solution could be to use third party software which allows access to several websites based on zones or groups (such as "block xxx sites").
Such tools could be located on a central server/firewall or on each client computer.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to better define "work orientated browsing".

If this is a list of X websites, then you could create a browser based "white list".

IE's in build settings have this option, look at Content advisor, it supports wildcards, so * could be used to restrict EVERYTHING BUT, the sites you want to allow.

The better and normal solution companies use is a content filtering system on a proxy, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the company database and the company SharePoint server are both on the company's own corporate network (as opposed to being hosted elsewhere), then it's dead simple to block all HTTP traffic, at least on the well-known ports, from getting through the firewall/router at the edge of the corporate network (that is, between the corporate network and the Internet connection).